# I want to change ListView Default Selection color in UWP(Universal Windows Platform) in Windows 10 for through out the Application

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am working on windows Universal Platform.  I am suffering from the default style of the `Xaml Controls`
Below there are some issue regarding `Controls` design:

- Change the List View Default Selection color
- Remove selected button background color
- Change the Default color of the Toggle Button
- Remove the Textbox on hover color

I Just tried code in `App.Xaml` but Which is not worked.

Code:

```
 <Application
    x:Class="MagePosSystem.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MagePosSystem"
    RequestedTheme="Light">


    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>




            <!--After selection - Background-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow"></SolidColorBrush>

            <!--When pointer hovers over an item - Background-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>

            <!--When the item is selected (first few milliseconds) - Background-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>

            <!--When the item is selected (first few milliseconds) - Border-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Black"></SolidColorBrush>


        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF05929" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF05929" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF05929" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF05929" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF05929" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFE45427" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFE45427" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFE45427" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FF808080" />


        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Whitetext" Color="White" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Black" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush1"  Color="White" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF65A2E" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF1683C" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchCurtainPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF1683C" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchCurtainPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFF1683C" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchThumbBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Black" />



        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButtonBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="LightGray" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RadioButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="LightGray" />


        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="LightGray" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush" Color="white" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="LightGray" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="LightGray" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the itemcontainer style of the listview. Use blend for that.

Change the value of SelectedBackground to change listview item selected color,

do the same for Button by changing the color in the pressed state. Similarly for other two issues.

```
<ListViewItemPresenter
                    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                    SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
                    CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                    CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}"
                    DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                    FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                    FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                    PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                    PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
                    PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                    SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"
                    SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                    SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
                    PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
                    SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
                    DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                    DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                    ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource GridViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    CheckMode="Overlay"/>
```

This is the style that gets applied. Change the value of the corresponding key.

Comment: yes, I know this thing  but i want to generalize the code at one place in app.xaml but which is not worked.you can see my code, I put all code in app.xaml but why it is not affecting to my application. I just want to know why app.xaml is not working.

Comment: :in which page i put this code?Because I used 20 Listview in my application so please suggest a better way which work as centralization so i don't have to work hard.

Comment: :Just Tell me how can i change the selectedbackground color to orange.

Comment: put your code in app.xaml so that you the style will be available through out the app. or better create a style targetting listviewitempresenter in you app.xaml and use that key to set your listview's itempresenter style. Clear?